# Send GridView's cell Data to Page when user select a record

Tags: asp.net

Imagine that i use below code for open a page when user select row in GridView (Click on )

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="Page1.aspx">Show</a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Is it possible to send GridView1.Rows[...][...].Text with `QueryString` to Page1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its posible.You need to bind your data 

Page1.aspx?myData=<%#Eval('your coulmn or propertie name')%>